# Server kernel panic after boot, don't know what to make of the logs

Tags: memory, central-processing-unit, kernel-panic, mcelog

We just received a brand new Dual CPU server and it keeps crashing with a Kernel Panic shortly after booting, this even happened during the OS setup when it was idle. I was able to get the OS installed and enable mcelog to try and understand what is happening, although I'm not sure what to make of the output. Reading online made me think this might be a defective DIMM on one of the Sockets (1) but I ran memtest with several passes and found no errors. Is it possible this is a Software issue instead? I've already tried 2 OSs and the same thing happened in both, although in Debian/Proxmox it was far more common to happen than in CentOS.

Server Specs:

Dual Intel 8-Core Xeon E5-2620v4

2 x DIMM 32GB DDR4 2400MHz RECC DDR4

MB SuperMicro X10DRL-i

It's not the CPU thermals because those never went above 35ºC during memtest or the OS install. I was also able to run some shorts benchmarks on the CPU before it crashed and the temps were OK.

How can I figure what what is going on here? I can have access to the server for a few minutes before it happens, I've already downloaded the vmcore dump but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Here's the mce log 50 seconds after it booted and then crashed:

```
[   56.367615] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[   70.420914] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[   71.886789] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   71.886894] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 24: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.887009] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.887122] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd362 
[   71.887184] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 11 microcode b00001d
[   71.887289] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.889392] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 30: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.889489] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.889595] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd11d 
[   71.889657] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 1d microcode b00001d
[   71.889760] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.891804] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 14: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.891901] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.892007] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd10e 
[   71.892068] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 1c microcode b00001d
[   71.892171] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.894217] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 13: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.894314] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.894420] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd23c 
[   71.894480] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 1a microcode b00001d
[   71.894585] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.896634] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 29: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.896730] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.896835] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd194 
[   71.896896] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 1b microcode b00001d
[   71.897000] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.899053] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 28: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.899150] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.899256] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd719 
[   71.899335] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 19 microcode b00001d
[   71.899438] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.901485] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 12: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.901582] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.901687] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd720 
[   71.901748] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 18 microcode b00001d
[   71.901851] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.903934] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 10: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.904031] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.904136] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd851 
[   71.904197] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 14 microcode b00001d
[   71.904300] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.906306] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 26: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.906403] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.906508] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd863 
[   71.906569] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 15 microcode b00001d
[   71.909482] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.914367] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 11: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.917304] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.920287] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd515 
[   71.923159] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 16 microcode b00001d
[   71.926031] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[   71.930820] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 27: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.933685] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.936557] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd449 
[   71.939384] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 17 microcode b00001d
[   71.944180] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 9: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.947059] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.949956] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd766 
[   71.952786] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 12 microcode b00001d
[   71.957580] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 25: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.960480] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.963366] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd751 
[   71.966210] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 13 microcode b00001d
[   71.971031] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 31: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.973919] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.976817] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd7f7 
[   71.979690] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 1f microcode b00001d
[   71.984474] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 15: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   71.987371] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   71.990290] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd803 
[   71.993151] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 1e microcode b00001d
[   71.997992] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 8: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 20: fa00004000020e0f
[   72.000918] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffff8138fb97> {intel_idle+0xd7/0x160}
[   72.003828] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 206cc7cd374 
[   72.006692] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:406f1 TIME 1487438906 SOCKET 1 APIC 10 microcode b00001d
[   72.011533] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check: Processor context corrupt
[   72.014436] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal machine check
```

Comment: Where did you purchase this server from? What are the details of its hardware? What did your vendor say about this error?

Comment: It's either going to be a CPU or the motherboard. Either way your vendor needs to be fixing this.

Comment: It was a local vender here, we've bought servers from them before with no problems. I will be contacting them tomorrow but their support is closed on weekends. Just wanted to try and figure out better what the problem might be.

@EEAA, server is a Dual Intel 8-Core Xeon E5-2620v4, 2xDIMM 32GB DDR4 2400MHz RECC DDR4, motherboard is MB X10DRL-i

Comment: Make a bootable version of the Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005567.html?wapkw=%28intel+processor+diagnostic+tool%29
Test RAM 1 (or 2) sticks at a time, and you can try to update the BIOS/microcode.

Comment: I think there's BIOS or hardware problem. If your motherboard supports hpet (high precision event timer) then enable it in the BIOS and use it in kernel boot parameter. But TSC is more recommended to use. If  BIOS update won't help you, then you need to change CPU or motherboard.

Comment: Yeah either motherboard or cpu. Maybe you need to install the cpus again. But I guess that at least one Cpu is faultry. Did you try to use only one cpu?

Comment: Can't seem to get Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool live version to work. It just boots fedora, documentation says it's supposed to auto install IPDT but nothing happens and I can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late reply I know but I completely forgot. It turned out to be one of the CPUs that was improperly placed, or maybe it got loose during shipping. At least that's what the vendor told me as they say they didn't replace a thing.

After they shipped it back everything was working.